# edit crontab of remote machine server bash remsh rsh

Tags: bash

i am trying to edit crontab of remote machine  is it possible ?

i am running

remsh REMOTEHOST -l REMOTEUSER crontab testcronfile

getting

crontab: can't open your crontab file.

error

thanks for help

HP-UX

Comment: May also want to try this questions on ServerFault.com, StackOverflow's sister-site for sysadmin questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that the file `testcronfile` is local. When you call remsh, it tries to open a remote `testcronfile`, which does not exists, hence the error message :)

You have to upload your testcronfile first.

Am I right ?

my2cents

Comment: You're welcome. A common error when you begin to do remote things :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried getting a remote interactive shell first, then executing the crontab command? If that also fails then it points the finger at the remote machine rather than how remsh connects. If it works then check the enviroments in both cases and look for differences (certain scripts only run on interactive login, for instance).

Good luck!

Comment: you mean rlogin ? then crontab

Comment: Yes. rlogin / rsh / ssh - whatever you'd normally use.